# Segmentation fault in array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, segmentation-fault, fault

try to get number of rows and column from user through array but it gives Segmentation fault at run time

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int rows;
    int column;
    int arr[rows];
    int arr1[column];
    
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    printf("Enter the number of column: ");
    scanf("%d",&column);
    printf("\n");
    
int i=0;
while( i<rows)
{  printf("\n");
   printf("Enter the value of rows index: " );
   scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
   printf("\n");
    i++;
}
int j=0;
while(j<column)
{
   printf("Enter the value of rows index: " );
   scanf("%d",&arr1[j]);
   printf("\n");
    j++;
}
}
```

// giving Segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

At the time of your definition for the "arr" and "arr1" arrays, the value of column and rows is undefined.

```
int rows;
int column;
int arr[rows];
int arr1[column];
```

Move the declaration of those arrays after you have received input from the user.

```
printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
scanf("%d",&rows);
printf("Enter the number of column: ");
scanf("%d",&column);
printf("\n");
int arr[rows];
int arr1[column];
```

Give that a try and see if that addresses your segmentation fault.